# Getting Observable Data from Parent and Child Http Requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following situation where I get an array of parent data, and then for each parent, make another http request to get the child data. This works fine, but the parent data of course arrives first, and then a second later the child data returns. Is there any way I can return a single observable that will only emit once all the data from the parents and children arrive?

```
return http.get('parent').map(parents => {
    return parents.map(parent => {
        parentData: parent.data
        child: http.get('child').map(children => {
            childrenData: children.data
        })
    })
});
```

EDIT: Working solution

```
const result = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').mergeMap((parents: any) => {
    const getParentChild = p => {
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').first().map((c: any) => {
            return {
                parent: p,
                child: c
            }
        });
    };
    return Observable.forkJoin(parents.map(p => getParentChild(p)));
});

result.subscribe(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: What was your edit for? You have received 2 answers, can you not work further from those answers? Would you enlighten readers what changed in the outcome, and what is still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hugo Novo mentioned above, `forkJoin()` is probably the best operator. This operator accepts individual observables as arguments, or an array of observables.

Pay attention that you'll need `mergeMap()` as well. When our map code returns an observable itself, we want to emit this last observable emission, not the observable itself.

- forkJoin(): when all children complete, return the last item emitted for each observable;
- mergeMap(): when all children complete, map and return each parent with their children;

```js
const parent$ = Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3].map(i => ({
  id: i,
  name: 'parent ' + i
})));
const child = (i) => Rx.Observable.of({
  id: i,
  name: 'child ' + i
});

const result = parent$.mergeMap(parents => {
  const getParentChild = p => child(p.id).map(c => {
    return {
      parent: p,
      child: c,
    };
  });
  return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(parents.map(p => getParentChild(p)));
});

result.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit to see if i'm missing something? All the http requests are going through, but nothing is being printed out.

Comment: hum...forkJoin is pretty strightforward, it only requires the input observables to complete. are you sure they complete after emitting? if they come from http service they complete. any runtime errors?

Comment: You're solution was correct. For some reason using the deprecated Http module worked, but not the newer HttpClient in Angular.

Comment: @EricLarson if the HttpClient succeeds, put a `.first()` just after them to make sure it is completed.

Comment: Could you explain why first() works in this instance?

Comment: @EricLarson Angular's Http service always completed the observable. Looks like new HttpClient doesn't. `.first()` takes the first item that is emitted, then completes the observable because no additional items are useful. Keep that `.first()` even though I think HttpClient should also complete observables just as before.

Comment: Do you have any idea why only the inner http request requires a first()?

Comment: @EricLarson you mean *parent* request completes but *child* does not? that's weird

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you’re looking for is the forkJoin operator

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

This operator is precisely to handle multiple observables and emit when all of them are complete